# keras: could not convert string to float in model.fit

Tags: python, keras

I have a data frame like this, of DNA sequences:

```
Feature         Label
GCTAGATGACAGT   0
TTTTAAAACAG     1
TAGCTATACT      2    
TGGGGCAAAAAAAA  0
AATGTCG         3
AATGTCG         0
AATGTCG         1
```

Where there is one column with a DNA sequence, and a label that can either be 0,1,2,3 (i.e. a category of that DNA sequence). I want to develop a NN that predicts probability of classification of each sequence into the 1,2 or 3 category (not 0, i don't care about 0). Each sequence can appear multiple times in the data frame, and it is possible that each sequence appears in multiple (or all) categories. So the output should look like this:

```
GCTAGATGACAGT   (0.9,0.1,0.2)
TTTTAAAACAG     (0.7,0.6,0.3)
TAGCTATACT      (0.3,0.3,0.2)    
TGGGGCAAAAAAAA  (0.1,0.5,0.6)
```

Where the numbers in the tuple are the probability that the sequence is found in category 1,2 and 3.

I wrote this basic code to get started. You can see I've commented out trickier bits, I'm trying to get a basic method working and then I'll gradually expand on it, but i've included everything so people can see the general idea I was thinking of.

```
# Split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
X = df.iloc[:,[0]].as_matrix() #as matrix due to this error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45479239/pandas-keyerror-not-in-index-when-training-a-keras-model
y = df.iloc[:,-1].as_matrix()
print(X[0:10])
print(y[0:10])


# Define 10-fold cross validation test harness
kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)
kf = kfold.get_n_splits(X)
cvscores = []
for train, test in kfold.split(X, Y):
    X_train, X_test = X[train], X[test]
    y_train, y_test = y[train], y[test]


# Pre-process the data
#    X_train = sequence.pad_sequences(X[train], maxlen=30) #based on 30 aa being max we're interested in
#    X_test = sequence.pad_sequences(X[test], maxlen=30) #based on 30 aa being max we're interested in




# Create model
    model = Sequential()
#   model.add(Embedding(3000, 32, input_length=30))
#   model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(20, return_sequences=True), input_shape=(n_timesteps, 1)))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))



# Compile model
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])



# Monitor val accuracy and perform early stopping
#    es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience=200)
#    mc = ModelCheckpoint('best_model.h5', monitor='val_accuracy', mode='max', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)



# Fit the model
    model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=150, batch_size=10, verbose=0)


# Evaluate the model
#    scores = model.evaluate(X[test], Y[test], verbose=0)
#    print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
#    cvscores.append(scores[1] * 100)
#print("%.2f%% (+/- %.2f%%)" % (numpy.mean(cvscores), numpy.std(cvscores)))


#output a three sigmoid model, and plot accuracy and loss
```

The output first prints the sequences, as expected (i.e. the print statement):

```
[['GCTAGATGACAGT']
 ['TTTTAAAACAG']
 ['TAGCTATACT']
 ['TGGGGCAAAAAAAA']
 ['AATGTCG']
 ['AATGTCG']
 ['AATGTCG']
 ['TTATATAAAAG']
 ['GCTGGGAG']
 ['TTTGCGTATAGATAGATAG']]
[0 1 2 0 3 0 1 2 2 0]
```

And then I get the error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'XXX' (where XXXX is one of the sequences in the data set, but not one of the top 10 in the output above), and further up in the error it points to the value error being in the line:

    model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=150, batch_size=10, verbose=0)
```

I did see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54370753/keras-valueerror-could-not-convert-string-to-float) question, but I don't think mine is the same root cause. Can someone explain why I'm getting this? I'm wondering is it because I haven't explained to the model yet/properly that I'm dealing with calculating probability of a sequence instead of a categorical feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see on the prints statement you are feeding your NN withs strings/text and this is not possible. You have to encode them into numbers. To carry out this operation different approaches are available: you can one-hot encode your characters or you can create a trainable embedding for each character.

I suggest you [Tokenizer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/text/Tokenizer) from TF which can help you in the process of numerical encoding of text sequences